# ¿Se puede cambiar el nombre de una funcion en las rutas de lumen?

Tags: laravel, lumen

Hola buenas tardes estoy trabajando con el microframework de laravel llamado lumen
y quisiera saber si puedo cambiar el nombre de una función diatónicamente según sea el valor que obtenga de la petición:

```
 $router->get('mapas/ultimaLectura[/{tipo}]',['uses'=>'MapasController@UltimaLectura[{tipo}]']);
```

Donde dice `[{tipo}]` tanto en la ruta como en la función de controlador.

O ¿Cual seria la forma correcta de hacerlo?

Comment: se podria hacer pero por cuestiones de seguridad no seria recomendable lo mejor seria crear un arreglo `$tipos=[ 1 => "index",2 =>"about",3=>"users"];` y dependiendo del valor que llege por {tipo} sea 1,2 o 3 se llama a la funcion correspondiente

Comment: Y como haria para llamar la funcion con el arreglo?

Comment: llamando a una funcion igual para todas ejemplo `public function tipos($t){
 if($t =="index"){
 $this.index()
}
}`

Comment: Lo estoy intententando pero no doy logro ponerla como dices